# Angular HTTPClient browser not adding headers

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient, request-headers

I am trying to use HTTPClient to upload a form to my backend server (Java/Springboot). When I try to add the authorization header, the network debug does not show the header added in my post request for upload.

Here is the code that I am using

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

.....
....


let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + AuthService.getToken());

this.http.post(serverURL, formData, {headers : httpHeaders}).subscribe(
  (res) => console.log('server response =' + JSON.stringify(res)),
  (err) => console.log('server err =' + JSON.stringify(err))
);
```

Here are the screenshots from the network debug

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can some one please suggest what could have caused this?

Comment: I could solve this issue by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901160/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-authorization-header?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471172/springboot-endpoint-403-options-when-doing-a-post-request

Answer (score 0):

```
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + AuthService.getToken());
```

You can use like this